# Books: customize chapter

Tags: books

I'm writing a book in LaTeX. This is my output: [image]

Is it possible to change the text "Capitolo" ("Chapter" in italian) with something else, for example "Experience"?

Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} % Typical maths resource packages
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{graphics}                 % Packages to allow inclusion of graphics
\usepackage{color}                    % For creating coloured text and background

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}                 % For creating hyperlinks in cross references. It should be after the color package. The option colorlinks produces colored entries without boxes. The option citecolor=blue changes the default green citations to blue.
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=12mm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}
\parindent 1cm
\parskip 0.2cm
\topmargin 0.2cm
\oddsidemargin 1cm
\evensidemargin 0.5cm
\textwidth 15cm
\textheight 21cm

\def\R{\mathbb{ R}}
\def\S{\mathbb{ S}}
\def\I{\mathbb{ I}}
\makeindex


\title{Laboratorio di Chimica Organica II}

\author{\htmladdnormallink           % Puts a hyperlink on to the author's name
{Marco Atzori}{}
{\copyright 2018 }}

 \date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indice}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Identificazione di una sostanza organica incognita}\normalsize
  %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\pagestyle{plain}
La sostanza da identificare è la numero 24. Nell'identificazione di una sostanza organica incognita la prima analisi da eseguire è la ricerca di un eventuale carattere acido o basico. A tale scopo, se ne verifica la solubilità in tre soluzioni acquose: HCl al 10\%, NaOH al 10\%, e $\ce{NaHCO_{3}}$ al 10\%. La sostanza non risulta avere un carattere acido perché non è solubile in acido cloridrico, mentre lo è in idrossido di sodio. A questo punto, bisogna ricavare una stima della forza dell'acido che si vuole identificare: la sostanza non è solubile in bicarbonato di sodio. Il saggio per l'identificazione dei fenoli con $\ce{FeCl_{3}}$ ha dato esito negativo, quindi un primo indizio è che si tratti di un acido carbossilico debole, presumibilmente aromatico.
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{ch1}
\include{ch2}

\include{index}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\addto\captionsitalian{%
    \renewcommand\chaptername{Experience}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Identificazione di una sostanza organica incognita}

\end{document}
```